# Artifactory not caching SOME npm packages from https://registry.npmjs.org 404 Not Found]

Tags: jenkins, npm, devops, artifactory

For one of my projects I spotted a strange behavior of Artifactory, maybe I' missing something...

So we have npm caching remote repo set up in Artifactory (added to virtual repo "npm"). Normally it works fine, but I'm getting 404 for two packages, which are normally available in https://registry.npmjs.org.

```
npm config set loglevel verbose
npm config set registry https://<url>/artifactory/api/npm/npm/
npm install --unsafe-perm
```

```
npm http fetch GET 200 https://<url>/artifactory/api/npm/npm/semver/-/semver-5.7.1.tgz 108ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://<url>/artifactory/api/npm/npm/@babel%2fparser 848ms

npm verb stack Error: 404 Not Found - GET https://<url>/artifactory/api/npm/npm/@babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from/-/plugin-syntax-export-default-from-7.12.13.tgz
npm verb stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/check-response.js:117:15
npm verb stack     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
npm verb stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
npm verb statusCode 404
npm verb pkgid @babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from@7.12.13
npm verb cwd /home/jenkins/workspace/eup_ledigtime_npm-cache
npm verb Linux 5.4.0-74-generic
npm verb argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm"
npm verb node v12.22.1
npm verb npm  v6.14.12
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://<url>/artifactory/api/npm/npm/@babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from/-/plugin-syntax-export-default-from-7.12.13.tgz
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from@7.12.13' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'eup_ledigtime_npm-cache'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Do you have any idea why I'm getting such errors?
**I've already tried to bypass head requests, zip repo, and reset cache.**
It doesn't find packaged neither from web browser, nor local npm (in the example I'm using Jenkins)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to run "npm cache clean --force"?

Comment: Hi, yes, no luck.

Comment: Would you consider using the JFrog CLI? It is much easier to use. You can config your npm build by running "jfrog rt npm-config" and then run "jfrog rt npm-install":
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-BuildingNpmPackagesUsingtheNpmClient